# Gazebo shuts down immediately

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hey,

I installed Gazebo 1.4.0 on Ubuntu 12.04 using apt-get at first and also compiling from source. The problem that I'm facing is that when I type in the 'gazebo' command, it shows the GUI for a second and then immediately shuts it down without giving any errors. What is the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1204/gazebo-shuts-down-immediately/) by [siddharth950](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/195/siddharth950/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-02-05

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Vaz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/171/daniel-vaz/) on 2013-02-05**:
Did you follow the step 5 of http://gazebosim.org/wiki/1.4/install ?

**Comment by [siddharth950](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/195/siddharth950/) on 2013-02-05**:
Yes I did. Does anyone have a working 1.4.0 version on Ubuntu 12.04?

**Comment by [siddharth950](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/195/siddharth950/) on 2013-02-06**:
I got it working! I installed a new copy of Ubuntu 12.04 and installed using sudo apt-get. It's working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,
firstly, let me apologise for writing this as an 'answer', I don't have enough Karma yet to post as a comment. I am in the same boat as the user above, and have been for a couple of weeks. I spent some time going through other posts, questions and answers looking for how to resolve this. I have tried various combinations of un-installing and reinstalling both ROS and Gazebo. Also, I have tried both 1.3 and 1.4 source installations, as well as the standard repository edition. The environment variables you asked for @nkoenig are as follows:

```
<user>@XPS-Ubuntu:~$ env | grep GAZEBO
GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH=/usr/share/gazebo-1.4:/usr/share/gazebo_models
GAZEBO_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11345
GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib/gazebo-1.4/plugins
GAZEBO_MODEL_DATABASE_URI=http://gazebosim.org/models
```

I have also triple checked paths and the like. Any suggestions would be very welcome as I would rather not have to do an OS reinstall as others have done to fix various issues.

If `gazebo` is called, the program crashes without an errors, sometimes it will get as far as the UI which will then go dark and crash, again without any errors. If `gzclient` is called after a successful `gzserver` or if `gzmaster` is called alone, we get the same result.

Thanks in advance and please let me know if there are further details you require. Again, sorry for posting this here in this format, however, I thought it better than starting a new question about the same issue.

---

Originally posted by [treanorj](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/193/treanorj/) with karma: 26 on 2013-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-02-06**:
What is the output of: `glxinfo | grep "direct rendering:"`

**Comment by [treanorj](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/193/treanorj/) on 2013-02-07**:
@nkoenig Hi, thanks for the quick reply. The output is:
`direct rendering: Yes`

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-02-07**:
can you open two terminals. In one terminal run `gdb gzserver` and in the other `gdb gzclient`. When gzclient fails, type `bt` at the gdb prompt. Post the out of the `bt` command.

**Comment by [treanorj](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/193/treanorj/) on 2013-02-07**:
Ok, so I have `gdb gzserver` happily working away in the first terminal, and in the second, I have `gdb gzclient` however while no gazebo comes up there does not seem to be a specified failure. When I type `bt` I get "No stack".

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-02-07**:
What happens when you just run `gzclient` in a terminal. Make sure that no `gzserver` is running.

**Comment by [treanorj](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/193/treanorj/) on 2013-02-07**:
Running `gzserver` alone waits at the
`Msg Waiting for master` line

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-02-07**:
Did you mean "Running gzclient"?

**Comment by [treanorj](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/193/treanorj/) on 2013-02-07**:
Yes, sorry, I mean running `gzclient`

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-02-07**:
Can you try running the pr2.world: `gzserver worlds/pr2.world` in one terminal, and in another terminal: `gztopic view /gazebo/default/pr2/head_tilt_link/head_mount_sensor/image`? The `gztopic view` command should open a window with a greyscale image.

**Comment by [treanorj](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/193/treanorj/) on 2013-02-07**:
Before I get to the gztopic point, after I start `gzserver worlds/pr2.world` I get the usual
`Msg Waiting for master`
`Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345`
`Msg Publicized address: 192.168.1.56`

Then multiple lines of the same warning:
`Warning [ODEJoint.cc:116] joint friction not implemented`
Which finishes then with a Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Apologies in the format of my replies, I don't know fully the wiki syntax.

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-02-07**:
In one terminal, first run `ulimit -c unlimited`. Then run `gzserver worlds/pr2.world`. The segfault should occur, and a new file will be created called `core`. Then run `gdb /usr/bin/gzserver core`. At the gdb prompt, type bt. Post this output in a new answer block so that it's more readable. Thanks.